# Django orm query_set

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I searched for various information on the Internet,

but I didn't get the desired results.

I am trying to get the following as my output but:

```
[
    {
        "vehicle__name": "AAA",
        "vehicle__number": "123",
        "user_id__first_name": ["name1","name2"],
        "vc": 8
    },
    {
        "vehicle__name": "BBB",
        "vehicle__number": "111",
        "user_id__first_name": ["name3"],
        "vc": 5
    }
]
```

I don't know what to do.

Can you help me?

My code:

```
a = TestManager.objects.filter(company_code__in=sub_company).values(
            'vehicle__name',
            'vehicle__number',
            'user_id__first_name'
        ).annotate(
            vc=Count("vehicle__name"),
        ).order_by(
            'vehicle__name',
        )
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "vehicle__name": "AAA",
        "vehicle__number": "123",
        "user_id__first_name": "name1",
        "vc": 9
    },
    {
        "vehicle__name": "AAA",
        "vehicle__number": "123",
        "user_id__first_name": "name2",
        "vc": 1
    },
    {
        "vehicle__name": "BBB",
        "vehicle__number": "111",
        "user_id__first_name": "name3",
        "vc": 10
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `Postgres`, you can try this:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg

a = TestManager.objects.filter(company_code__in=sub_company).values(
    'vehicle__name',
    'vehicle__number'
).annotate(
    vc=Count("vehicle__name"),
    user_id_first_names=ArrayAgg('user_id_first_name', distinct=True)
).order_by('vehicle__name')
```

Comment: I've been searching the internet for ArrayAgg, but I'm still not very familiar with how to use it, so I'm not getting the results I want. Thanks for your help.

Comment: My pleasure, sir! And if my answer to the original question was helpful, feel free to mark it as right.